# Can Eclipse GMF (Graphical Modeling Framework) be used to create a standalone modeling IDE?

Tags: java, modeling, eclipse-gmf, emf

I want to create a graphical modeling application.

I've been working on all the drag and drop functionality and then I thought about GMF/EMF, but it is used to create Eclipse plugins, at least from what I've seen at:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework_FAQ#What_can_I_do_with_GMF.3F

> **What can I do with GMF?** Using GMF, you can produce graphical editors for Eclipse. For example, a UML modeling tool, workflow
>   editor, etc. Basically, a graphical editing surface for any domain
>   model in EMF you'd like.

My question is if it is also possible to create stand alone applications with this framework (one that does not need Eclipse to run?) and if not do you know of any useful framework for this purpose?

Comment: See also [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) - also Eclipse-RCP based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GMF to create a so-called RCP application (rich client platform), as described in [part 4 of the GMF Tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GMF_Tutorial_Part_4). The resulting editor will be much smaller and more light-weight than a full eclipse, but also quite limited; e.g. I found it impossible to add additional (custom) views other than the editor window, properties and outline view.

Note: I have not used this myself (just tinkered a bit) and I am not sure, how mature this is.

Comment: thanks , after reading the tutorial i felt that this is not the right framework for my needs , as it was kind of complicated to set up and i felt there was not enough support , for now i am checking JUNG

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can create a standalone RCP application ( like Eclipse IDE product)  and your modeling plugins will be part of it.
You need to define product to launch your plugins with your editors.

`GMF` provides you default graphical views/editors but first you need to define `EMF` models to generate it.

Comment: but will it be possible (or more important easy/practical) to implement the standalone so that i can change the EMF models dynamically at run time

Comment: I dont understand "change EMF metadata at runtime". Do you mean just change EMF model and re-generate code?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains very well how to do that: http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=1476&lang=en